# Http header value in server side rendering angular

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, user-agent, angular-universal

I'm working with angular and my site is being served through SSR. In one of my directive I want to know the value of `user agent`, since the page is being built through SSR, I don't have access to the `window` object (in order to get the `window.navigator.userAgent`). So, in this case, how can I get the value of UserAgent in my code.
I know in Backend code (I have myself done this for PHP) we can use the `request` object to get the HTTP headers, can we similarly get that `User-Agent` value here as well inside the directive?